# storing encrypted data in Windows registry

Tags: c#, registry, password-encryption

Can you store an encrypted password in the Windows registry?

I have to find a way to store a connection string (which will contain a password to a MIcrosoft SQL Server database) in the local machine's registry.

I have seen some advice on here (and other places) regarding encrypting the data and THEN storing it in the registry, and doing the reverse for decryption (read value from registry and then use application/program to decrypt value), but can the registry store all of the characters that may be used by (say) 128-bit encryption (basically, can it store non-alphanumeric characters).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also, encryption won't do you any good unless you have a secure place to store the encryption key.  You need to figure out what you're trying to defend against. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt using CryptProtectData, which does not require a key. Then save it in the registry using RegSetValueEx with data type REG_BINARY.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of resources on the net to assist you with this. For example, you can use AES to encrypt and decrypt a string. I've found a good example [AES Encryption, Dream in Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156922-aes-encryption-and-c#/).

Microsoft also talk about understanding what to protect yourself with, and even some ideas.

[Protecting Connection Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

From my quick browse through the net, I would suggest creating a custom config which you have as an embedded resource, so hopefully no one would access, then reference it in your config file like below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
</configuration>
```

More information about this config is available here : [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This way, you wouldn't have to deal with someone with limited computer access, like in a  business domain, complaining he needs an administrator to install the program :)

Hope this helps.

Happy coding!